# Simple solution to archive dovecot/postfix emails to second server nightly for long term storage with roundcube access

Tags: linux, email, email-server, dovecot, archive

Our email server has ~150 email accounts containing material that cannot be deleted for 10 years.  Some accounts are heading towards 10gb of data so I'd like to setup a nightly archive process that takes the older emails and places them onto another server that could be accessed if/when needed.

Our setup uses: dovecot, postfix, roundcube, ubuntu and virtualmin/webmin.

My initial thought was to `rsync` the files using a cron job, but the concern is lost data/headers, etc.  So, then I thought I could do a `doveadm sync -1`, but after reading about the sync process it runs, my concern is that the headers will be misaligned and cause duplicates to be archived.

I've also seen posts about tools out there that do this - not my initial preference, but open to the conversation.  I've also seen some more complicated c/pearl scripts, but these are not my strong suits (though my background is programming, so I'm not opposed to this).

Has anyone had great success using `doveadm sync -1`? Would either of these work since the server will only be receiving emails in this one manner, never directly or through another source?  Or,  has someone had great success another way or can point to an online document/tutorial/solution?

Comment: What specific *problem* are you trying to solve with the split? 150 simultaneous users and 1.5TiB total storage does not sound unwieldy enough by itself to justify backups schemes beyond asynchronous incremental full drive copies, while keeping live IMAP access limited to one hot server.

Comment: Yes, that's all we have now.  For years we have done a manual purge to a second server on a regular basis as email accounts are closed or they hit the 8+gb to help RoundCube work efficiently.  We've also increased our server hardware (AWS) as we've gone.  We're looking a way to efficiently clean/speed up the system while keeping access to the old files if needed. I'm not knowledgeable enough to push back with logic - is there any documentation that outlines what mailbox sizes should be able to go to, what hardware is needed as they grow and when they should be purged?

Comment: Try to enumerate possible bottlenecks and see which one is routinely hit. Does the server always have a few gigabytes of available memory to use for caches? Are the drives boring themselves to death but always ready to deliver 500k IOp/s? Is the IMAP server doing cheap indexed searches for almost all client requests? Is the network latency between the IMAP storage and the webmail client well below 1ms? Does the webmail client never idle waiting for processing or database slots? If a request takes time, what is it: First folder access, first full text search, retrieving large attachments, ..?

Comment: I appreciate your approach. I will do some more testing.  If I recall the original issues correct, they were: 1) searching in roundcube was slow; and 2) MS Outlook was hanging.  Researched suggested reducing mailbox  size and that resolved the issue, so we started to do it manually and never looked back. I'll do a bit more load testing and make sure I fully understand the issue here.

Comment: Hm. If you have to support thin clients and "lets try to download everything" clients at the same time, my approach may lead nowhere. If you only need Roundcube... fast indexed searching for thin clients used to be finicky, but has seen substantial progress in more recent Dovecot versions.

Comment: Thanks again - I'll do the tests, but also interested in the best solution to the backup method if anyone has one.